# why cannot prove convergence of a serie with it's limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, self-learning

i have the following serie

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{{\sqrt{k} + k^3}}{{k^4+k^2}} $$

is it enough to calculate the limit to prove that it converges ?

so that would be

$$\lim_{k \to \infty } \frac{{\sqrt{k} + k^3}}{{k^4+k^2}} = 0 $$

so we may say the serie converges to 0.

doing it this way is wrong or right ?

Comment: It's very wrong. The terms you're adding converge to $0$; this does not imply their sum converges. Try using the Limit Comparison Test with $\sum {1\over k}$.

Comment: what about `Ratio test` ? $\lim_{k \to \infty} \|{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}}\|$

Comment: No, the limit involved in the Ratio Test will be $1$.

Comment: For **any** series to converge, the terms must converge to 0. Clearly not all of them sum to zero though.

Answer (score 2):

This series actually does not converge.
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{{\sqrt{k} + k^3}}{{k^4+k^2}}$$
Let $$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{{\sqrt{k} + k^3}}{{k^4+k^2}}$$

Then $S_n>\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{{k^3}}{{k^4+k^2}} =\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{{k^2+1}}$ which is equivalent to the harmonic series $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{{k}}$, which diverges.

Note that the fact that the term of the series converges to zero does not guarantee at all the convergence of the series ; witness the harmonic series.
To investigate whether the series converges or not, you have a number of different tools : D'Alembert test, Cauchy test, equivalences, majoration etc.